# Windows Task Manager equivalent for OS X, showing more details than Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, software-rec, task-manager

Being a Windows convert, I am looking for [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) equivalent for OS X.

Please do not recommend Activity Monitor, since it misses two important features of Task Manager:

- per process disk i/o (read, write, other)
- simple process description (like what is this 'mds' process? where does it live?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[atMonitor](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/atMonitor.shtml) is a more advanced Activity Monitor. It definitely fulfils the second of your requirements, in that it provides quite a lot of information about each process.

As for per-process IO, the only way I know is the command line tool 'iotop' which comes with the Mac. Open Terminal.app in an administrator account and type:

```
sudo iotop
```

There may be some debugging output as the program runs, but it should show the information you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a handy widget for your dashboard called iStat Pro. It's not the same as a task manager application but it does allow you to quickly and easily see your most interesting running processes (and a number of other useful stats about your Mac)

Answer (score 1):

I provided an answer to [a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19918380/117259), and I find that using [`htop`](http://themainframe.ca/2011/06/install-htop-on-mac-os-x/)—a tool commonly used in the Linux world—is far better & clearer than the standard tools Mac OS X uses. My fave use is to hit the `T` key while it is running to view processes in tree view (see screenshot). Shows you what processes are co-dependent on other processes.

[image]

And if you have Xcode and related tools such as `git` installed on your system and you want to install from a source repository—such as [max-horvath’s `htop` GitHub repository](https://github.com/max-horvath/htop-osx)—just follow these steps.

First clone the sourcecode from max-horvath’s `htop-osx` GitHub repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:max-horvath/htop-osx.git
```

Now go into the repository directory:

```
cd htop-osx
```

Run `libtoolize` and `automake -f` like this:

```
libtoolize && automake -f
```

Then run `autogen.sh`:

```
./autogen.sh
```

Run this `configure` command:

```
./configure
```

Once the `configure` process completes, run `make`:

```
make
```

Finally install it by running `sudo make install`:

```
sudo make install
```